# How to interrupt epoll_pwait to catch signal

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, epoll

I would write a small test that shows me the difference between `epoll_Wait` and `epoll_pwait()` by catching any interrupted signal. can anyone provide me by a small code or any method to find that?

```
int epoll_pwait(int epfd, struct epoll_event *events,
                  int maxevents, int timeout,
                  const sigset_t *sigmask);
```

Comment: Do you have some code? For sending signals, I suggest reading `man 1 kill`and `man 2 kill`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a way to integrate signal handling in an `epoll` event loop, have a look at the `signalfd(2)` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html).

It will give you an fd which you can add to your pollset to be notified when your process (or thread, if that is relevant in your case) has received a signal.

Answer (score 1):

epoll_pwait does not "catch signals", it allows you to atomically set a new process signal **mask** which is only active during the call. See the description on the man page, e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_wait

What is it you are trying to achieve? if you are more specific, I might be able to give you more information.